# exceptions that spring cassandra connect and session creation can throw?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

```
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(host).build();  
Session session  = cluster.connect(keyspace);
CassandraOperations cassandraOps = new CassandraTemplate(session);
```

I am looking for exceptions other than nullPointerException and noHostAvailableException?

Comment: The place to look is in the source code.  It is unlikely to be documented anywhere else (reliably / definitively), and the only way someone here can give you an answer is by reading the code for themselves.  So just short-circuit the process ... and read it yourself.

Comment: I dont see any given in the documentation for cassandra cluster and session specifically other than noHostAvailableException. Is it fine to share the link where this is described?

Comment: Google for it.  Search for the fully qualified classname and "source".  Or go to the Spring site and navigate to the page with the source code repositories.  (I could do the work for you ... but if you do it yourself you will have learned a new "research" technique.)

Comment: There is not any exception for http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraOperations.html and http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.html ; though couple more exists for Cluster and Session(ClusterAuthenticationException and IllegalStateException)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything throws DataAccessException.  That is one of the fundamental points of Spring Data.  We translate the C* exceptions into predictable, standard exceptions thrown by all Spring Data modules.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html?is-external=true